# How to import and use my own function from .py file in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, import

In Jupyter Notebook I created my own function in my_fk.py file like below:

```
import pandas as pd

def missing_val(df):

    df= pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes, columns=["type"])
    df["missing"] = pd.DataFrame(df.isna().any())
    df["sum_miss"] = pd.DataFrame(df.isna().sum())
    df["perc_miss"] = round((df.apply(pd.isna).mean()*100),2)
    
    return df
```

Then when I try to import and run my function using below code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import my_fk as fk
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
    fk.missing_val(df)
```

I have error like below. Error suggests that in my my_fk.py file there is no pandas as pd, but there IS line with code "import pandas as pd". How can I import and use my own function from python file ?

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: Okay. The problem is the first line of your code. `df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")`  . You didn't import pandas before running that. You should move up the import statement on the second line.

Comment: WIthThree I edited my question,

Comment: did you try running it again after the edit? and where is the error coming from(which line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing "as". Then place your pd.read_csv() after importing pandas, not before

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import my_fk as fk


df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
fk.missing_val(df)
```

Comment: I did like you but Unfortunately I still have error: NameError: name 'pd' is not defined :( Do you have other idea ?

Comment: You can try to restart your python kernel to see if it will fix the problem

Comment: wow!! You are right, I had to restart kernel, thant you, I gave you best answer :)